# ArangoDB How to get all neighbours with fulldepth matching the pattern with AQL?

Tags: graph, arangodb, nearest-neighbor, aql

We have ~300k document and ~3m edge in our ArangoDB v3.2
I want to get all neighbors of start document and neighbor's neighbours as long as neighbor's rate > 0.5.. It will give me the community has rate > 0.5 and related with start doc.

Now i m doing it with multiple requests but data and project is going to be bigger and i need better performance so **i need a AQL query to get all neigbours with one request**..

I have tried to get neighbours with depth 1..10 so it will enought to get all neigbours but it is very ver slow so i cant give absolute depth..

```
for vertex, edge, path in 1..10 any 'docs/10' doc_relations
    filter edge.rate > 0.5
return distinct edge
```

I need some thing like while loop but there is no query function like this.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer.
I extended the arango with [User Functions](https://docs.arangodb.com/3.2/AQL/Extending/). **You can write any function with javascript after add it to arango you can use it on aql**. You can use any query of aql in your js too. I wrote a js and added it on arangosh

To add a user function write it and save it a file has extension ".js"

Lets say for example we saved the js function to ***path/to/func/file.js***

First select a db to add new user func

```
db._useDatabase("dbName");
```

You can add it like this

```
require("@arangodb/aql/functions").register("MYFUNCNAMESPACE::SEARCHRELATEDCLIPS",   require("path/to/func/file.js"), false);
```

Note: 3 th parameter added for future versions it not works for v3.2

You can unregister like this

```
require("@arangodb/aql/functions").unregister("MYFUNCNAMESPACE::SEARCHRELATEDCLIPS");
```

---

*Neighbor search function in path/to/func/file.js*

```js
function searchRelatedDocs( docID )
{
 var db = require("@arangodb").db;
 var groupDocs = [];
 var unSearchedDocs = [docID];
 var searchedDocs = {};
 var stepCounter = 0;
 var searchedDocCounter = 0;
 var start = new Number(new Date());
 var edgeSearchTime = 0;
 while( unSearchedDocs.length > 0 )
 {
  searchedDocCounter++;
  var docID = unSearchedDocs.shift();
  groupDocs.push(docID);
  
  searchedDocs[docID] = true;
  var startE = new Number(new Date());
  var docEdges = db.doc_relations.edges( docID );
  edgeSearchTime += ( new Number(new Date()) - startE );
  if( docEdges == null || docEdges == undefined || !( docEdges instanceof Array && docEdges.length != 0) )
   continue;
  
  for( var i = 0; i < docEdges.length; i++ )
  {
   stepCounter++;
   var edge = docEdges[i];
   
   
   if( edge.rate > 0.5 )
   {
    var relatedDocID = undefined;
   
    if( edge._to == docID )
    {
     relatedDocID = edge._from;
    }
    else
     relatedDocID = edge._to;
    
    if( searchedDocs[relatedDocID] == undefined )
    {
     searchedDocs[relatedDocID] = false;
     unSearchedDocs.push(relatedDocID);
    }
   }
   
   
  }
   
  
 }
 var end = new Number(new Date());
 
 var result = {};
 result.time = ( end - start );
 result.searchedDocs = searchedDocCounter;
 result.searchedEdges = stepCounter;
 result.edgeSearchTime = edgeSearchTime;
 var documents = db.docs.documents(groupDocs);
 
 if( documents != undefined && documents != null && documents.documents != undefined && documents.documents instanceof Array )
  result.vertices = documents.documents;
 
 return result;
}


module.exports = searchRelatedDocs;
```

> Don't forget to add **module.exports = funcName;** in file.js.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you should be able to achieve what you want using AQL.

#### Fine-tuning the AQL query

It looks like you could fine-tune the definitional AQL query. Specifically, I would propose using an AQL query along the following lines:

```
for vertex, edge, path in 1..100000 OUTBOUND 'docs/10' doc_relations
   OPTIONS {uniqueVertices: "global", bfs: true }
   FILTER path.edges[*].rate ALL > 0.5
   return vertex
```

That is:

- if possible, use `OUTBOUND` rather than `ALL`;
- use the `OPTIONS` as shown since you don't care how many admissible paths there are to an admissible vertex;
- your requirements seem to impose the "rate > 0.5" restriction on **every** edge along an admissible path to a "neighbor", hence `ALL`;
- since you want the vertices, simply return `vertex`; there is no need for `DISTINCT` because of the aforementioned `OPTIONS`.

#### Add a "skip-list index" on .rate

#### Cacheing the neighbours in the database

> i need a AQL query to get all neigbours with one request

In terms of performance, there is obviously a time/space tradeoff here, and it might make sense to pre-compute the neighbours of all the vertices, or to compute-and-cache them on demand.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But  i cant give absolute depth because of performance and there can be a neighbours after 10th depth and bfs is not good for this search reason.. With my answer i m geting it in 20~80ms. It is true search type for this type of problems

Comment: It is true that AQL requires that a value for MAX be specified but if necessary you could try a very large value (3000000 ?).  If bfs turns out to be infeasible, then maybe `uniqueVertices: path` would help? Is the `FILTER path.edges[*].rate ALL > 0.5` acceptable? Can you share a database that exhibits the interesting properties of your actual database?

Comment: I'm using mmfiles db type so if i give 3000000 depth for only 1 search the doc and doc_relations collections will be locked and my whole system will wait for this operation. And it uses so much ram too because of loading too much document and edge. This query must go on true path and uniqueVertices must be global. I think AQL need another traversal type..

Comment: I created a graph with a path length of 1,000,000 (one million), and ran a query like the one in my post (using `bfs:true`) with MAX set to ten million; it completed on my rather old computer in 19 seconds using ArangoDB 3.2.   As I said, if you could
 share a graph that exhibits the interesting properties of yours, I'd be interested to take a look.